# How to fire Property Set for Textboxes bound to numeric data

Tags: wpf, textbox, properties, double, numeric

I just noticed that WPF textboxes bound to numeric data **do not** fire `Property Set` when non-numeric events happen such as letters/spaces typed or text cleared.  This becomes a problem when I'm trying to validate that a textbox has a valid number.  If the user types in 5 and presses backspace, the databound property remains 5 while the textbox appears empty!  I have no way of disabling a button to stop further progress.  Is there anyway to enable non-numeric notifications when bound to numeric data?  Or, am I forced to use a string property/data converter?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not like the default converter you need to create your own which returns a valid value if the input is empty or unparsable.

```
public class IntBindingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int outInt;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out outInt))
            {
                return outInt;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Max">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <vc:IntBindingConverter/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This may look a bit messy but normally you in fact just stop the user from proceeding.

Comment: I decided to subclass TextBox and override `OnTextChanged()` so when this.Text was null/empty I would set it to "0".  Since you're probably right about the default converter and your code would definitely solve my problem, though, I'll accept your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Subclassing TextBox for that sounds like massive overkill to me but to each their own...

Comment: Haha, not just for that - it also allowed me to prevent letters from being typed

Comment: That is more reasonable, i would probably use input validation via `ValidationRules` for that though.

Comment: I implement IDataErrorInfo in my viewmodel where I switch on columnName and call `ViewModelBase.Validate(() => _model.Property)`.  Each property has a ValidationAttribute applied that indicates how Validate should validate it.  This method avoids cluttering my XAML and provides a way for my model to say that it's valid.  How would ValidationRules let the VM/M know when all properties are valid?

Comment: ValidationRules make sure that invalid data is never passed back to the data-object in the first place. But since you cannot stop the user they are not applicable here either.